# How to Convert Fire base Child Added result Value to Json list using Ionin (angular js)

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

I want to convert the firebase result to JSON list (dynamially).

```
ref.child("USERS").child(localStorage.getItem('id')).child("ADDRESS").on("child_added", function(snapshot)  
{
    var data = snapshot.val();          
});
```

I need the list like this:

```
$scope.AddressList = 
[
    { Name: "Sampel" },         
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `child_added`, use the `value` event to retrieve and listen to the entire node for changes.

```
ref.child("USERS").child(localStorage.getItem('id')).child("ADDRESS").on("value", function(snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val();          
});
```

This will return an object.

Comment: Its working. but only four objects is there but length show 5.Please help.